# How to use annotations instead of web.xml in the servlet to specify url

Tags: servlet-3.0

How to provide an annotation mapping for web.XML in annotation. I have done with web.XML. I
want to try with Annotation mapping, like so:

```
<web-app> 
  <servlet-mapping> 
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple example is :

```
@WebServlet(value="/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    // then write the data of the response
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    if (username != null && username.length() > 0) {
        out.println("<h2>Hello, " + username + "!</h2>");
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

**[Annotation](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212220811/https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations)** represents the metadata. If you use annotation, deployment descriptor (web.xml file) is not required. But you should have tomcat7 as it will not run in the previous versions of tomcat. @WebServlet annotation is used to map the servlet with the specified name.

```
@WebServlet("/Simple")
public class Simple extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        
        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<h3>Hello Servlet</h3>");
        out.print("</body></html>");
    }

}
```

Comment: I already got solution,if you want to answer,I have posted one question check it.