# Maven Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required when building the SpringMVC project with pure Java Based Configuration and no xml's

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I am developing a Spring MVC project with pure Java based configuration. I am getting the error below when I do a Maven clean install.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on
>   project SpringMVC-ShoppingCart: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute
>   is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update
>   mode) -> [Help 1]

The error says that `web.xml` is missing, but I did not have one since I used pure Java based configuration.

How to make sure that the project builds and creates war file without `web.xml`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This error happens because the [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/), in version 2.6 or lower, expects by default a `src/main/webapp/web.xml` file to be present in your WAR project, and it didn't find it.

#### Use annotations and upgrade to 3.0.0 or newer

As of version 3.0.0 of the plugin, the presence of a `web.xml` [is not mandatory by default anymore](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-war-plugin/#Hint_for_release_3.0.0):

> The default value for `failOnMissingWebXml` has been changed from `true` to `false`.

This means that upgrading the plugin directly solves the issue. You can add the following configuration in your POM:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</plugin>
```

The reason is that since Servlet 3.0, the `web.xml` file is no longer needed in a web application, and [can be replaced with annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259153/do-i-really-need-web-xml-for-a-servlet-based-java-web-application) to have a Java-based configuration ([MWAR-262](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-262)). However, since your project might not use annotations to replace this file, in which case the `web.xml` could actually be missing, a sanity check was added in version 3.0.1 of the plugin to make sure that the annotation [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) is in the compile classpath of your WAR project ([MWAR-396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-396)). If it isn't, and there is no `web.xml` file in your project, the plugin will still fail by default.

#### Ignore the missing `web.xml`

If you just want the plugin to explicitly ignore a missing `web.xml` file, regardless of the usage of annotations, you can set the [`failOnMissingWebXml`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) parameter to `false`. A sample configuration would be:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have not included web.xml in your web project and trying to build war using maven. To resolve this error, you need to set the failOnMissingWebXml to false in pom.xml file.

For example:

```
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>   
</properties>
```

Please see the blog for more details: https://ankurjain26.blogspot.in/2017/05/error-assembling-war-webxml-attribute.html

Comment: this work for me on mvn ver 3.5.1, the accepted answer didn't

Comment: this answer works if your not using the maven-war-plugin but just packaging as war