# Is web.xml required to deploy a spring boot application

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, war

I was trying to package a spring boot application as a war. According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html), I modified my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"org.mdacc.rists.cghub.model"}) 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.mdacc.rists.cghub.ws.repository"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
         return application.sources(Application.class);
     }
}
```

Also added the following in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I package the project though, I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project cg-web: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
```

As I was reading upon spring boot application, I never saw anything about creating a web.xml. Is web.xml required in deploying spring boot application as war?

Comment: Did you add `spring-boot-starter-web` as dependency? For more info see:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: @Aliaxander yes, but should I specify the scope as provided for this one as well?

Comment: No, you shouldn't.

Comment: Try to add the following:
`<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>`
according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390460/maven-error-assembling-war-webxml-attribute-is-required-when-building-the-sprin

Comment: @Aliaxander It works thanks. Can you change the comment to answer so I can close the ticket?

Comment: Great, I added the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33390519/4423968) answer make *Maven* ignore the *web.xml* absence by adding the following snippet to your *pom.xml*:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the web dependencies.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

You can always have your web.xml if you need some configuration on it, just place the file in the correct folder within WEB-INF so spring can take it an read the configurations. Also change the packaging to

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Consider as well use the parent pom for spring-boot as

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

This configuration

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Only tell maven not to include tomcat dependencies in the war file, to avoid interference with the servlet provider.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need `web.xml` file to create `WAR` artifact ready to be deployed.
Here is how I build `Spring Boot`-based artifacts using **Gradle**.

*build.gradle:*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE"

    //Allows to run spring boot app on standalone Tomcat instance
    providedRuntime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.3.3.RELEASE"
}
```

In order to build `WAR`, one should run:

`gradle war`

Comment: I am not familiar with gradle. How do I package it with maven?

Comment: @Nasreddin with maven, use `mvn package`

Answer (score 1):

In servlet 2.5 specs (java EE 5) , web.xml is mandatory, in servlet specs 3+ (java EE 6) , you can remove web.xml and use annotation configuration instead