# Remove the web.xml file with Google Guice

Tags: java, servlets, guice

If I relate to the [documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Servlets) of Guice I can :

> completely eliminate web.xml from your servlet application

But I can't find a way to create a servlet listener from Guice so I still need the web.xml file.

Do I missed something or is it really impossible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I really need web.xml for a Servlet based Java web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259153/do-i-really-need-web-xml-for-a-servlet-based-java-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by *servlet listener* you mean a `ServletContextListener`. You are using the Guice `ServletModule`. You should use (and probably are using right now if following Guice documentation) the `GuiceServletContextListener` also to bootstrap your modules.

In this situation you want to throw your own `ServletContextListener` and not write a `web.xml`. You can do that. You have several options.

You can just add the `@WebListener` annotation to your class.

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
   ...
```

That has a problem (for me). You have two listeners (this one and the guice derived one) but you don't know which one goes first.

My solution for this is to just have one (the guice one) which calls my other, general purpose, listener.