# How to configure a non-spring pure javaee web-application without web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, annotations, web.xml

I want to create a simple web application that runs on tomcat with pure java configuration.
I know how to do it with Spring frameworks `WebApplicationInitializer`. But i don't know without Spring.
I have heard about `@WebServlet` 
Please guide me.

Comment: Why without web.xml? It isn't Spring stuff, web.xml is JavaEE stuff.

Comment: This is true that from Java EE 6, web.xml is no longer required for a web app to deploy. Instead of using xml, you can use annotations to replace the xml file. Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236743/how-to-use-annotations-instead-of-web-xml-in-the-servlet-to-specify-url

Comment: @Rouliboy : I was exactly looking for this reply. You can make it the answer if you want.
BackSlash :  I dont understand the point of downvoting this question when Java EE allows to create web apps without web.xml file.

Comment: @Kazi : I updated the answer. Glad if this helped you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true that from Java EE 6, web.xml is no longer required for a Webapp to deploy. Instead of using web.xml, you can use annotations to replace the xml file (`@WebServlet`, etc.)

More information is given in this thread : [How to use annotations instead of web.xml in the servlet to specify url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236743/how-to-use-annotations-instead-of-web-xml-in-the-servlet-to-specify-url)