# how to remove extension of a file from jsp

Tags: java

http://localhost:8080/pvPreet/index.jsp

Hi all,
  I want to remove extension from the above link. Exactly i want a solution which is applicable for all the jsp files available in my project.
Right now i am using the below code for this purpose and it is working fine as well but using this code for each and every file is not an good idea. That's why i was looking for an standardize way for this purpose. So please help!

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: i am using this code for this purpose                                             
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Put (using [Edit]) your code inside your question.

Comment: edit your post and add the code there... not in a comment as sometimes they are not immediately viewable. This limits the ambiguity in your question.

Comment: Since he ain't doing it, I formatted it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using `jsp-servlet` instead of just using jsp to do it all. When using `jsp-servlet` you can using annotation to specify your servlet path and do not need the mapping. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236743/how-to-use-annotations-instead-of-web-xml-in-the-servlet-to-specify-url)